# How to get exact data from nested data in json

Tags: json, hbase, apache-nifi

I have tried SplitJson and EvaluateJson processor but i cant get proper data
For example:

```
{
   "affiliate": {
    "name": "affiliate",
    "apiLists": {
        "category1": {
            "availableVariants": {
                "v1.1.0": {
                    "resourceName": "category1",
                    "put": null,
                    "delete": null,
                    "post": null
                },
                "v0.1.0": {
                    "resourceName": "category1",
                    "put": null,
                    "delete": null
                }
            },
            "apiName": "category1"
        },
        "category2": {
            "availableVariants": {
                "v1.1.0": {
                    "resourceName": "category2",
                    "put": null,
                    "delete": null,
                    "post": null
                },
                "v0.1.0": {
                    "resourceName": "category2",
                    "put": null,
                    "delete": null,
                    "post": null
                }
            },
            "apiName": "category2"
        }
    }
   }    
}
```

I want to store that "category1" which is in apiLists and also want "category2"

Answer (score 0):

Umang soni,

Add the below configuration in the EvaluateJsonPath and create two attributes 'Category1' and 'Category2'.

```
Destination: flowfile-attribute
ReturnType :auto-detect
Category1: $.affiliate.apiLists.category1
Category2: $.affiliate.apiLists.category2
```

It will get your category1 contents into that attribute named "Category1" as well as "Category2".

**EDIT-1**
In case you don't know the category name you can use following configuration in evaluateJsonpath.

```
Destination:flowfile-content
ReturnType:auto-detect
ApiLists:$.affiliate.apiLists
```

Here all categories put into flowfile in json. Now you can split it by using SplitJSON processor.
Hope this helpful for you.

Comment: Thank you sir. But What should i do if i don't know the name of category or i don't want to write name of particular category and want to get category loop wise (like one by one)..? 

Actually i have many categories and want to store these categories into hbase one by one (for example store category1 in one row with it's unique row identifier. That's why i want to get categories one by one

Comment: Yeah its possible. Check my Edit-1 in answer and don't hesitate to be accept it to be answer.